# Failed to connect to remote host in wildfly11

Tags: wildfly-11

We are using AWS windows wildfly 11 application .

We are able to access the application without any issues with VPN connection. But we are getting the errors with the URL without VPN.

We are able to access the application but not able to login without VPN connection, we are getting below error i.e; problem with remote errors.

Can anyone help me with solution.

```
12:04:49,360 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN AppServiceLocator:] javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information]
12:05:10,403 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN AppServiceLocator:] javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information]
12:05:31,408 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN AppServiceLocator:] javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information]
12:05:31,408 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN GETTING REMOTE HOME:] interface com.ipacs.framework.controller.interfaces.ServerControllerHome
12:05:31,410 ERROR [EJBModelLoader] [AppServiceLocatorException:]
com.ipacs.als.gui.exception.AppServiceLocatorException: [ERROR IN GETTING REMOTE HOME:] interface com.ipacs.framework.controller.interfaces.ServerControllerHome
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.util.AppServiceLocator.getRemoteHome(AppServiceLocator.java:93)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.EJBModelLoader.doBusinessAction(EJBModelLoader.java:83)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.EJBModelLoader.doBusinessEvent(EJBModelLoader.java:66)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.ModelLoader.doBusiness(ModelLoader.java:37)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.callBizService(BusinessEventHelper.java:285)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:175)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:167)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:162)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:348)
    at com.ipacs.ntuc.Startup.initProject(Startup.java:232)
    at com.ipacs.ntuc.Startup.main(Startup.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
12:05:31,420 ERROR [Startup] com.ipacs.als.gui.exception.AppServiceLocatorException: [ERROR IN GETTING REMOTE HOME:] interface com.ipacs.framework.controller.interfaces.ServerControllerHome
Kewill Forwarding Application Run Time Exception
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.EJBModelLoader.doBusinessAction(EJBModelLoader.java:104)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.EJBModelLoader.doBusinessEvent(EJBModelLoader.java:66)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.ModelLoader.doBusiness(ModelLoader.java:37)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.callBizService(BusinessEventHelper.java:285)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:175)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:167)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:162)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.BusinessEventHelper.doBusiness(BusinessEventHelper.java:348)
    at com.ipacs.ntuc.Startup.initProject(Startup.java:232)
    at com.ipacs.ntuc.Startup.main(Startup.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ipacs.als.gui.exception.AppServiceLocatorException: [ERROR IN GETTING REMOTE HOME:] interface com.ipacs.framework.controller.interfaces.ServerControllerHome
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.util.AppServiceLocator.getRemoteHome(AppServiceLocator.java:93)
    at com.ipacs.als.gui.model.EJBModelLoader.doBusinessAction(EJBModelLoader.java:83)
    ... 18 more
12:05:52,566 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN AppServiceLocator:] javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information]
12:06:13,575 ERROR [AppServiceLocator] [ERROR IN AppServiceLocator:] javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information]
```